# How can I change the UI when user taps the native remote controls?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change the play/pause button's text when the user taps the native remote control. I'm using custom fonts.

This is my code:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.StatusChanged += Current_StatusChanged;

private void Current_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CrossMediaManager.Current.Status == MediaPlayerStatus.Playing)
    {
        PlayPause.Text = "c";
    }
    if (CrossMediaManager.Current.Status == MediaPlayerStatus.Paused)
    {
        PlayPause.Text = "b";
    }
}
```

When debugging, the code is executed, but the text isn't changed. After tapping the remote control, when I use the app's buttons, I can't change the text either.

How can I achieve this?

Edited:

This is the Xaml code of the label:

```
<Label Text="b" TextColor="#d92632" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource TextoRojoReproductor}" VerticalOptions="Center"
                   x:Name="PlayPause">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PlayPause_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: The playpause is a Label in your xaml? Can you provide more context and code?

Comment: Please add the xaml for this and other relevant code

Comment: Also, tell me what exactly do you mean by `native remote control`

Comment: The xaml code was added to the edited question. Native remote control are the device buttons for play/pause actions, when the display is blocked.

Comment: Are you sure that it enters the  if statement?

Comment: Yes, it hits the PlayPause.Text = "b"; line, but  nothing happens. Then, after tapping the remote control, I cannot change the text, even using the app buttons.

Comment: Could you give me more information about the using custom fonts. You can try to use default fonts and make a test.If you use android emulate, you can open logcat to find some errors or warings

Comment: The behavior is the same using standard letters. I just use a font file, when letters from 'a' to 'h' are characters like play, pause, next or previous.